# C++ coroutines / Visual Studio: How can a generator call a function that yields values on its behalf?

Tags: c++, generator, coroutine

With coroutines defined as of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4628.pdf and implemented in VS2015/Update 3, how can a generator invoke a function that emits values on its behalf?

**Clarifying example**

I would like to write code as follows...

```
static void yield_for_me()
{
    co_yield 27; // does not compile 
                 //  co_yield relies on hidden definitions
}
std::experimental::generator<int> testf()
{
    yield_for_me();
    co_yield 28;
}
```

...in hopes that it will have the exact same outcome as the following code:

```
std::experimental::generator<int> testf()
{
    co_yield 27;
    co_yield 28;
}
```

Comment: a natural follow-up to this is "what is the equivalent c++ code generated under the hood by the co_yield keyword" ?  -   it would be helpful to understand the underlying scaffolding.

Comment: Not that it's helpful: Given the linked spec, I don't seem to see a way -- the equivalent in python would be `yield from` -- hopefully they implement something similar in c++ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `co_yield`/`co_await`/`co_return` in a function turns it into a coroutine, thus it needs to have a signature that allows compiler to discover library classes explaining to the compiler what that coroutine means.

The generator included with Visual Studio does not support delegating `co_yield` to another generator. But is is not difficult to  create a `recursive_generator` that can.

Here is an example of a recursive_generator that allows to yield either a value or the result of execution of a different generator.

https://gist.github.com/GorNishanov/29e813139175b1c5299ad01021d2556d

The promise_type of the recursive_generator defines two `yield_value` functions:

```
yield_value(T const&); // This one yields individual values
yield_value(recursive_generator<T>&&); // delegates to another generator
```

Using the recursive_generator above, just change the return type of yield_from_me function from void to recursive_generator and you are good to go.

```
recursive_generator<int> yield_for_me()
{
    co_yield 27; 
}
recursive_generator<int> testf()
{
    co_yield yield_for_me();
    co_yield 28;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can't. It's a well-known limitation of the coroutine model proposed by P0057.
Although in the paper, it also describes a `recursive_generator` (not included in MSVC) that allows you to do something like this:

```
recursive_generator<int> yield_for_me()
{
    co_yield 27;
}
recursive_generator<int> testf()
{
    co_yield yield_for_me();
    co_yield 28;
}
```

BTW, such a thing is implemented in [CO2](https://github.com/jamboree/co2), which is an emulation of the proposed model.